# Prevent columns from stacking when view port changes? (BS)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have modified the navbar in bootstrap to use x-scroll instead of the hamburger/dropdown style. The problem I am having is .navbar-nav and .navbar-header are stacking on mobile and I need them to remain inline.

I have tried lots of methods but they're all extremely messy and inconsistent.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-nav {
  float: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1u7zyehs/2/

I know the default behaviour of BS is to stack containers on mobile, is there a clean way to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the media query targeting mobile devices, you can add the following...
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1u7zyehs/2/)

```
.navbar-header{
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work... BS is mobile first so it shouldn't need a media query to target mobile.. queries in BS start from 720px. I think the container is being assign display:block which is giving it 100% width.. CSS to reverse that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: In the fiddle the rule you suggest is missing. Maybe that is why the demo is not working. Fixed here http://jsfiddle.net/1u7zyehs/5/

Comment: Yes indeed, but sometimes to meet our design requirements we need to add or edit some classes. Since both div and ul are block level elements, they are stacking up. Else you can use the bootstrap grid to align them eg. col-xs-6 for div and ul.

Comment: @TasosK. they are still stacking in your fiddle?

Comment: No, links are on the left of `Brand` and links have a horizontal scroll.

Comment: Just tried another browser, works in Chrome (thanks).. still stacks in Safari :(